# I can't access my own "votes" page and get an ASP error

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, 500-server-error

Something is going on when trying to access [my "votes" tab](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck?tab=votes).

[image]

I checked with other users on SU and other mods – nobody seems to be able to reproduce this.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody was able to reproduce this because the **votes** tab remembers the last sub-tab that was open.

- If I open any other sub-tab and click **deletion** or **undelete**, I get no error, but nothing happens.
- If I visit https://superuser.com/users/101836/dennis?tab=votes&sort=deletion or https://superuser.com/users/101836/dennis?tab=votes&sort=undelete directly, I get redirected to https://superuser.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/101836/dennis.

Comment: Yep. I can vouch for that. How do you get back now? - http://superuser.com/users/289/chrisf?tab=votes&sort=all

Comment: The question was somewhat tongue in cheek :)